# How to type the symbol for "hybrid dynamical system" in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

How do I type the symbol for "hybrid dynamical system" in LaTex?
Please see the attached screenshot of the symbol.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Just load the `amsymb` package in the preamble and type `\mathcal{H}` (in math mode) in the body of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{H}$
\end{document}
```

For finding certain symbols, the [symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) is a useful reference.

Comment: Thank you @kubo